# diagbox with babel RTL tabular issue

Tags: luatex, babel, right-to-left, patching, diagbox

I have issue with `\diagbox` in RTL tabular (`babel` with `bidi=basic`, `lualatex` engine), with xelatex `bidi` package provide patch of diagbox commands for right to left tabular, but for lualatex there isn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic-r,layout=tabular]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\diagbox[dir=SW]{Time}{Day}&two\\
three&four
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if we add graphics layout

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic-r,layout=tabular.graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\diagbox[dir=SW]{Time}{Day}&two\\
three&four
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very likely you can temporarily switch the direction with `\babelsublr` or an LTR language (restoring the language if the internal text is RTL). Currently `graphics` only deals with `picture` (and `pict2e`) and `tikz` (at least the basic functions). I'll open an issue.

Comment: Thanks @JavierBezos I need `\diagbox` in RTL tabular ( with `layout=tabular`)

Comment: @JavierBezos or this may be done in `diagbox` package and  It can be used either   with `bidi` (xelatex) or `babel` like this `\diagbox[rtl=on]{Time}{Day}` ?